# Making a setup for C#/SQL app

Tags: c#, sql, installation

this is my first post in stackoverflow, I've always checked this site by searching in google, so I decided to join it myself! I hope to be useful to others

I'm a 3d developer (DirectX), but recently I've started making an SMS gateway using C# and SQL Express, now I'm going to create a setup file for my project (which uses .NET 3.5), what are my options? I've heard that VS 2008 can make setup, is there any sample? how can I include SQL express in my setup app?
also I've downloaded Install Shield 2010 which has a built-in support for VS 2008, I want to make my setup in a way that it detects SQL on target system and if it finds SQL already installed, doesn't try to install it again (the same rule can be applied for .NET), what are my options? how can I make such a setup file?

thanks

Comment: @harpo That's one of the things SQL Express allows. They're called Named Instances. Here's a ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165614(v=sql.90).aspx. The install has support for creating the named instance for your app.

Comment: @Ritch, interesting.  I deleted my remark, but yeah.  I guess I'm just used to the developer-oriented install, which is pretty heavy.

Comment: @harpo On the flip side, don't confuse my comment with support for databases. I despise them. If you absolutely need some sort of concurrency engine, then by all means, use a Db for your locking semantics. However, most people use them as a data-store, and get wound up in the relational, are my constraints correct, use StoredProcs nonsense and make a simple serialization task complicated. I hate the things.

Comment: @Ritch, provocative.  But supposing you get past the nonsense to a sane methodology, aren't RDBMS queries handy?  Still, I know what you mean.  SQL Server is unbelievable overkill most of the time I've used it, especially standalone, as I (unfairly) assume is the case here.

Comment: @harpo - Yes, working with sets and queries is a really natural and safe (no state) way of working with data. The List<> class was great before Linq came along. Linq (to objects) is awesome. F# (and other functional languages) are incredible.

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft's Visual Studio, there is an inbuilt Setup Template which you can use.

- [**Click Once**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

  For your scenario you should take a look at Adding Click once [Custom Prerequisites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).
- [**Setup And Deployment**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) Application

  For your scenario you should take a look at the [Walk-through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/206sadcd%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Or as you mentioned you have InstallSheild 2010 then:

- Install Shield Wizard

  Take a look at this [Walk-through with Limited Edition](http://codesmartnothard.com/InstallShieldLimitedEditionForVisualStudio2010Walkthrough.aspx)

As for SQL Server i think you can usually go as far as SQL Server Compact Edition. (For anything greater you may need to Inform User to install it himself)

Answer (score 0):

I have no personal experience with it, but [SQL Server 2008 Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) might be good for this. It is an embedded solution so so you don't actually need to install a server. Alternatively you could look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), which has native .NET implementations (google for "sqlite .net").