# SQL Server Express C# application install combination

Tags: c#, sql-server, deployment, installation, sql-server-express

What is the best way to deploy SQL Server Express Edition with an application for release?  We also need to bring the data along as well.

I read that you use the SQL Server Express MSI installer, but how do we go about importing all the tables, views, sproc, data, etc?

This will be deployed to multiple customer sites and we need to start testing an install.

Any ideas will be greatly welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177086/making-a-setup-for-c-sql-app

Comment: just do attach/restore db during deployment or just script your db and run it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ship an MDF with your application and attach it at application runtime using the information at the following MSDN page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165716.aspx

This is similar to the way visual studio/ASP.Net attaches MDF files in App_Data.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  This might be just the answer I was looking for.  time to experiment :)